# Is there an equivalent to F# |> (method chaining) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, f#, chaining

I have an example in F#:

```
let a n = Convert.ToString(n:int32)
```

And I can say:

```
3 |> a
```

which evaluates to `"3"`. Is there a similar construct in Ruby?

This is F#'s (and other FP languages') method chaining, which is not function composition, nor is it method chaining in Ruby, i.e., objects that return self so that other methods on the object can be called as in `a.b.c.d`.

Comment: FFR: If all you want is to convert a `3` integer to a string `"3"`, then Ruby let's you simply do `3.to_s`

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty easy to implement in Ruby. Taken directly from the F# Reference Documentation:

```
let function1 x = x + 1
let function2 x = x * 2

let result = 100 |> function1 |> function2
//> val result : int = 202
```

This can be written in Ruby as follows:

```
function1 = -> x { x + 1 }
function2 = -> x { x * 2 }

result = 100.pipe(function1).pipe(function2)
# => 202
```

With the following implementation of `Object#pipe`:

```
class Object
  def pipe(callable)
    callable.(self)
  end
end
```

Or with your example:

```
a = -> n { String(n) }

3.pipe(a)
# => '3'
```

And

```
let f x y = x * y

3 |> f(2)
// > 6
```

becomes

```
f = -> (x, y) { x * y }

3.pipe(f.curry.(2))
# => 6
```

Comment: Does Ruby support partial application? Piping is mostly useful if you don't have to declare the single argument function independently...

Comment: Things get more complex when you need function currying behaviour which is possible in F#, but will require a whole new DSL in ruby. E.g. `let f x y = x * y` and then `3 |> f(2)`

Comment: @IgorS.: `f = -> (x, y) { x * y }; 3.pipe(f.curry.(2))`

Comment: Though it's still a DSL, your solution is a beginning of a really cool OSS project. Thanks for posting it here

Comment: @JörgWMittag
Thank you Jörg for your excellent answer.  I've posted a complete discussion of both pipelining and composition in an [article on the Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/668478/Function-Composition-Function-Chaining-Currying-an)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't support this F#/Ocaml/Haskel notation. Though I believe you can do something about it. But the point is that you shouldn't.

If you want to implement things in a functional style (which is great), you can use the `Enumerable` functionality ruby provides - `inject`, `map`, `select`, etc.

It will result in a clean readable ruby code with no hacks.

PS: +1 for the question. I asked it myself too when first started with ruby.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such notation but you could add a method to `Object` that passes `self` to a given method. Something like:

```
class Object
  def pass_to(m)
    m.call(self)
  end
end
```

This would allow an invocation like this:

```
def convert_to_string(n)
  n.to_s
end

def reverse_string(s)
  s.reverse
end

123
  .pass_to(method(:convert_to_string))
  .pass_to(method(:reverse_string))
#=> "321"
```

Or using lamdas:

```
convert_to_string = -> n { n.to_s }
reverse_string = -> s { s.reverse }

123
  .pass_to(convert_to_string)
  .pass_to(reverse_string)
#=> "321"
```

This is equivalent to sending the [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) message to `123` (returning `"123"`) and then sending the [`reverse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-reverse) message to `"123"`:

```
123
  .to_s
  .reverse
#=> "321"
```

Comment: You can just pass the method as a symbol in pass_to and in Object#pass_to do this: m = method(:m). Thought it might be more readable this way (rather than repeating "method" all the time as an argument to pass_to.